# ControlTemplate edit inside Resource hangs visual studio 2008

Tags: .net, wpf

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 in XP

The hang up occurs when i try to edit a controltemplate that is defined in a resource. 
(all my resource files are merged through application.xaml)

Googling this issue i found out that it is a known bug to microsoft, but i cant seem to find a hotfix or a good enough solution in order to do my work.

One way to do my work is to temporary exclude the resource file from the project, alter the controltemplate and then re-include and build project. 
But still, even this doesnt seem to work every time and i get about 1 hang up every 4-5 tries..

One other way is to copy the controltemplate inside a window.resources, make all the modifications and then copy it back to the resources file, But this is a pain in the ass to implement.

Anybody found a better way? or a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the bug.  Also have to been able to track down what part of the ControlTemplate is causing the hang.  Can you attach it to your question?

Comment: Are you using the WPF designer for .xaml files? Have you tried mapping the .xaml extension to the XML editor instead?

Comment: Bendeway: 
I could not find an actual BUG in microsoft, check out this page http://www.blagoev.com/Blog/post/Visual-Studio-2008-released-Too-early.aspx (search for 2.3.8.6.) 
This is supposed to be written in visual studio readme file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a hotfix for this: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958017

This hotfix is allready included in Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 so i guess thats why it doesnt affect everybody.

Answer (score 1):

It usually works fine for me if I just don't have any other XAML windows open. I think it's the designer in the window trying to use the resource that actually causes the crash.

Comment: simple yet effective!
Thank you.